# Showing QMenu without window

Tags: python, pyqt

Sorry i am a newbie in python pyside.
I'm trying to show a single poup menu.
Is it possible to show just a QMenu ( pyside ) window by itself without any other parent application window ?

Comment: Just don't let the parent application window be visible. Otherwise, gui's, like to have references to their parents. If that doesn't work, what have you tried?

Comment: I did not tried, i just saw in an example file. The menu was set with the setMenu to a popupButton. So I should skip this process and show it by itsside without any button. Sorry i sad i was a newbie. :)

Comment: So this is a theoretical question, where the suggested outcome likely doesn't exist...

Answer (score 0):

A [`QMenu`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmenu.html) is a subclass of `QWidget`, and so it can be shown as a top-level window (i.e. one without a parent). You can easily test this for yourself:

```
>>> from PySide import QtGui
>>> app = QtGui.QApplication([])
>>> m = QtGui.QMenu()
>>> m.addAction('Hello World')
<PySide.QtGui.QAction object at 0x7f13b6b65b08>
>>> m.exec_()
```